# If statement in python not working however else value is returned

Tags: python, if-statement

I have question. I don't understand why the code isn't executed. Only the else value is returned. Please help. Huge desperation. Thank you in advance!

```
def discounted_price(unit_price,quantity):
    if unit_price >= 200:
        discounted_price=(0.9*unit_price)*quantity
    elif quantity >= 20 and quantity%5==0: 
        discounted_price=unit_price*(quantity-(quantity/5))
    elif quantity >= 20:
        discounted_price=unit_price*(quantity-int(quantity/5))
    else:
        discounted_price=unit_price*quantity
        return discounted_price
```

Comment: You only ever `return` a value in the else statement. You probably want to de-dent your return statement by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python indentation is important, to return values from all condition the return statement has to be outside of else scope, like this:

```py
def discounted_price(unit_price,quantity):
    if unit_price >= 200:
        discounted_price=(0.9*unit_price)*quantity
    elif quantity >= 20 and quantity%5==0: 
        discounted_price=unit_price*(quantity-(quantity/5))
    elif quantity >= 20:
        discounted_price=unit_price*(quantity-int(quantity/5))
    else:
        discounted_price=unit_price*quantity
    return discounted_price  # <-- changed indentation
```